# SQL Transpose \ Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, transpose

I am trying to do a weekly summary of individual items from the original table.
The query should return 1 row for each specified Item type (i.e. Doors, Windows, etc)
if no item is returned, it should return null values

```
Original Table
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+------+
|ITEMID | Date      |ItemType  |Account No |Amt    | Desc |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-01 | Doors    |12345      |10     | ab   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-02 | Doors    |12345      |10     | cd   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-03 | Doors    |12345      |10     | ef   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-04 | Doors    |12345      |10     | gh   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-05 | Doors    |12345      |10     | ij   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-06 | Doors    |12345      |10     | kl   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|
|10     |2014-01-07 | Doors    |12345      |10     | mn   |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------|------|

target table:

+----------+-----------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| ItemType | AccountNo | Amt1 | DESC1 | Amt2 | Desc2 | Amt3 | Desc3 | Amt4 | Desc4 | Amt5 | Desc5 | Amt6 | Desc6 | Amt7 | Desc7 |
+----------+-----------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| Doors    | 1234      | 10   |  ab   | 11   |  cd   | 12   |  ef   | 13   |  gh   | 14   |  ij   | 15   |  kl   | 16   |  mn   |
+----------+-----------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
```

I was able to put together the below query for this task based on the answer below, but is there a better, more efficient way to do this????

```
  SELECT t1.Amt AS amt1, t1.desc AS desc1, t2.amt AS amt2, t2.desc AS desc2,t3.Amt AS amt3, t3.desc AS desc3
```

t4.amt AS amt4, t4.desc AS desc4, t5.amt AS amt5, t5.desc AS desc5 , t6.amt AS amt6, t6.desc AS desc6, t7.amt AS amt7, t7.desc AS desc7,
 FROM mytable t1
 INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.date='2014-01-01' AND t2.itemid=10 AND t2.type='Doors' 
 INNER JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.date='2014-01-02' AND t3.itemid=10 AND t3.type='Doors' 
 INNER JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.date='2014-01-03' AND t3.itemid=10 AND t4.type='Doors'
 INNER JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.date='2014-01-04' AND t3.itemid=10 AND t5.type='Doors'
 INNER JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.date='2014-01-05' AND t3.itemid=10 AND t6.type='Doors'
 INNER JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.date='2014-01-06' AND t3.itemid=10 AND t7.type='Doors'
 WHERE t1.itemid=10 AND t1.type='Doors'

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t1.Amount as [Jan 1 Amount],
t1.Description as [Jan 1 Desc.],
t2.Amount as [Jan 2 Amount],
t2.Description as [Jan 2 Desc.],
t3.Amount as [Jan 3 Amount],
t3.Description as [Jan 3 Desc.],
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t2.date='jan 2'
inner join table t3 on t3.date='jan 3'
where t1.date='jan 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PIVOT`

```
select 
[Jan 1Amount], [Jan 1Desc], [Jan 2Amount],
[Jan 2Desc], [Jan 3Amount], [Jan 3Desc]
from 
(
  select 
  [date] + column  as column,  value
  from Table1
cross apply
(
select 'Amount', convert(varchar(20),[Amount])  union all
select 'Desc', [Description]
) a (column, value)
) b
pivot
(
 max(value)
 for column in ([Jan 1Amount], [Jan 1Desc], [Jan 2Amount],
             [Jan 2Desc], [Jan 3Amount], [Jan 3Desc])
) pi;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea45e/17)

If the columns are unknown then you can use Dyanmic pivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Date] + ' ' +  col) 
                from Table1
                cross apply
                (select 'Amount', convert(varchar(20),[Amount]) 
                 union all
                 select 'Desc', [Description]
                ) c (col, so)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT   ' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
            select 
           [date] +'' '' +  col as col, value
           from Table1
        cross apply
         (
          select ''Amount'', convert(varchar(20),[Amount]) 
           union all
           select ''Desc'', [Description]
         ) c (col, value)
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(value)
            for col in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


execute sp_executesql @query;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/273db/14)